# Rails Tutorial (3rd Ed) Integration tests not running because of invalid css selector (c9.io ?)

Tags: railstutorial.org

I'm going through the Rails Tutorial (using the cloud9 ide)
(3rd Edition https://www.railstutorial.org/book/)
and I'm running into something odd.

I've just finished chapter 7, and I'm just now noticing that some of my assertions from chapter 5 are not running because "The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector."

Here's the contents of my test/integration/site_layout_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?", contact_path
    assert_select "a[href=?", signup_path
  end
end
```

It seems to be a character for character match to the code found in
 https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition/blob/master/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb

the errors that I'm getting are as follows

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector.=======                                           ] 66% Time: 00:00:00,  ETA: 00:00:00
unexpected '$' after '[:equal, "\"/\""]' (called from block in <class:SiteLayoutTest> at /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector.
unexpected '$' after '[:equal, "\"/help\""]' (called from block in <class:SiteLayoutTest> at /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:8)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector.
unexpected '$' after '[:equal, "\"/about\""]' (called from block in <class:SiteLayoutTest> at /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:9)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector.
unexpected '$' after '[:equal, "\"/contact\""]' (called from block in <class:SiteLayoutTest> at /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:10)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector.
unexpected '$' after '[:equal, "\"/signup\""]' (called from block in <class:SiteLayoutTest> at /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:11)
```

What I find really interesting is that if I delete all of the content from my stylesheets, I still get the same errors.

I have no clue as to where the term "about_path" (or any of the other path symbols) is picking up a $ char.

Am I missing something obvious, I can't find any references when I google the the warning text that has helps me track things back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing closing square brackets in your a[href] arguments. Your code should be as follows:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", signup_path
  end                      
end
```

Comment: Exactly my problem.  I stared at that code for at least 15 minutes and believed I was doing a character by character comparison.